# How do I retain extras in an Intent, when the appliction is not loaded on the device

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have an application that receives notifications from MyFirebaseMessagingService. The intent for the notification is set to the Login activity which also the Launcher/Main activity from the manifest. I am doing this so that if the user is not logged in, it requires a login before viewing the content/result of the notification.

When the application is running, everything works fine (the extras are attached to the intent) and I forward it to the destination activity using another intent.

When the application is NOT running, it launches the application, without the extras. A bundle object for the extras exists but does not have any of the original extras in it.

The following is my code for the generation of the intent from MyFirebaseMessagingService.

```
public void sendCheckInNotification(Context context, String messageBody, String messageTypeIn, String messageIdIn) {
        generateRequestCode(messageIdIn);
        Log.i(TAG, "MyFirebaseMessagingService: " + messageTypeIn + " " + messageIdIn + " sendCheckInNotification: ");
        sendingActivity = "NewCheckInNotification";
        Log.i(TAG, "MyFirebaseMessagingService sendCheckInNotification: sendingActivity= " + sendingActivity);
        Intent intent = new Intent (context,  Login.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("checkInTablePrimaryKey", assignedCheckInTablePrimaryKey);
        intent.putExtra("checkInTableFirebaseKey", checkInTableFirebaseKey);
        intent.putExtra("sendingActivity", sendingActivity);
        Log.i(TAG, "MyFirebaseMessagingService sendCheckInNotification: extras added=  " + sendingActivity);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE); }
        else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        }

        String channelId = context.getResources().getString(R.string.new_check_in_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.check_in_notifications_header))
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle())
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setGroup(NEW_CHECK_IN_NOTIFICATION_GROUP)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "New CheckingIn Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(requestCode /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

The following is the code for the receipt of the notification.  It finds a bundle for the object, but the extras are missing.

```
 extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Log.i(TAG, "Login onCreate: extras= " + extras);
        if (extras != null) {
            sendingActivity = extras.getString("sendingActivity");
            Log.i(TAG, "Login onCreate: sendingActivity = " + sendingActivity);
            if (user != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Login onCreate: user is not logged in for notification");
                if ((sendingActivity.equals("NewCheckInNotification")) ||
                   (sendingActivity.equals("PeepsWatcherUpdateNotification")) ||
                   (sendingActivity.equals("CheckInUpdateNotification")) ||
                   (sendingActivity.equals("CheckInLocationProvidedNotification")) ||
                   (sendingActivity.equals("NewCheckInLocationRequestNotification")) ||
                   (sendingActivity.equals("NewCheckInRequestNotification")) ||
                   (sendingActivity.equals("NewCheckInRequestUpdateNotification")) ||
                   (sendingActivity.equals("NewCheckInChatMessageNotification")) ||
                   (sendingActivity.equals("NewCheckInPicturesNotification"))) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Login onCreate: extras exist ");
                    setIntentForNextActivity();
                }
                else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Login onCreate: unknown sendingActivity for Intent " + sendingActivity);
                    }
            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Login: user not logged in"  );
                String message = "You will be directed to your notification after logging in";
                CustomToast newtoast = new CustomToast(context,message);
                newtoast.show();
            }
        }
```

The following is the manifest entry for the launcher activity

```
 <activity
            android:name="Login"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="Peeps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: You can use ```BroadcastReceiver``` for this purpose.

Comment: Where does `requestCode` come from, and is it always unique?

Comment: Also, you might want to add some debug logging to log the extras that are in the `Intent`. It is interesting that there is a `Bundle`, but it doesn't have the extras you are expecting. If you log the extras, that may help figure out where they come from. You can do this by iterating over all the extras in the `Bundle` and log them to logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the intent flags in your `sendCheckInNotification`, method to include `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` as below-

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

In the receiving activity's `onCreate` method, `override the onNewIntent` method and call setIntent with the new `intent`

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Retrieve the extras in the receiving activity's onCreate method after calling setIntent

```
extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Make your receiving activity singletop as below-

```
<activity
    android:name="Login"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="Peeps"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I tested with what you recommended. The onNewIntent never gets called.    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Login onNewIntent: ");
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        extras = intent.getExtras();
        Log.i(TAG, "Login onNewIntent: extras= " + extras);
        if (extras != null) {
            sendingActivity = extras.getString("sendingActivity");
............. more code

Comment: I changed it to force the call to onNewIntent from within the onCreate for the launcher activity.  The extras are null on the intent.

Comment: The extras exist on the intent when sending from MyFirebaseMessaging serivce, but when it gets to the receiving activity (launcher activity), the extras are gone.

Comment: try to make activity singleTop

Comment: It is single top

Comment: I think you doing mistake  in your code. try to debug step by step.